# How to add different icons in different table cells using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add distinct images but either one image gets loaded in all the cells or none. I am pasting the code for you guys. What's the problem?

```
<script>
function AddImage()
{
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("done"+i).innerHTML = "<img   
        src='icons/done.png' height='16' width='16' />";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: did not understand your question, if u have 6 div with id like done1,done2 , u want different image for different div or u want single image for all div

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this :

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.src = 'icons/done.png'; 
   <script>
        function AddImage()
    {
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
             document.getElementById("done"+i).appendChild(img);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

**Thanks & Cheers :)**

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your images, like `done1.png`, `done2.png` and so on, then change function to
`document.getElementById("done"+i).innerHTML = "<img src='icons/done' + i + '.png' height='16' width='16' />"`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to update the img `src` with `i` inside the loop. The `src` is always the same path: `icons/done.png`.